# use mantine-react-table V1 and mantine V7 with Nextjs 14 App Dir

Tags: npm, next.js13, mantine

I have a **Nextjs 14.1.0** project that uses **mantine-react-table** which has **mantine V6** dependencies:

```
"@mantine/core": "^6.0.21",
"@mantine/dates": "^6.0.21",
"@mantine/hooks": "^6.0.21",
"mantine-react-table": "^1.3.4"
```

In the same project I would like to use the **mantine V7** components.

I have tried to install **mantine V7** like this:

```
npm install v7@npm:@mantine/hooks@7.5.1
npm install v7@npm:@mantine/core@7.5.1
```

But I get this error:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: test-app@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: @mantine/hooks@6.0.21
npm ERR! node_modules/@mantine/hooks
npm ERR!   @mantine/hooks@"^6.0.21" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @mantine/hooks@"7.5.1" from v7-mantine-core@7.5.1
npm ERR! node_modules/v7-mantine-core
npm ERR!   v7-mantine-core@"npm:@mantine/core@7.5.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

How can I use install and use **mantine V7** components without affecting **mantine-react-table** dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

The [Mantine React Table docs](https://www.mantine-react-table.com/docs/getting-started/install) say MRT V1 will not work with Mantine V7.  You must either use Mantine V6 or update to [Mantine React Table V2](https://v2.mantine-react-table.com/docs/getting-started/install#installation) which is still in beta.